# Run Excel Macro Without Re-Opening Excel File Python

Tags: python, vba, excel

I am trying to run a python script utilizing windows task manager to call a macro at a certain time. I am able to currently run the script, but I've noticed that if the file is open, it re-opens it. I'd like to be able to call it on the file without having to re-open it so that other things running on the excel file don't need to shut down. Here is what I am using:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def RunExcelMacro():
    myExcel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    myExcel.Visible = 1
    myExcel.Workbooks.Open("filepath.xlsm")
    myExcel.Run('runMacro')
    myExcel.DisplayAlerts = 0

RunExcelMacro()
```

This is working code, but again it re-opens the excel file which i am trying to avoid.

I know there is a way to do this with a VB Script, but I am trying to see if I can do this all in Python.

Comment: Since you put the vba tag on this... From within VBA (or .NET) I'd call GetObject (GetActiveObject) on the file name. If it's open, that will pick it up, otherwise it will open the file. Not sure what the equivalent would be for Python, but FWIW... The other approach would be to loop the Workbooks collection checking whether the file name is one of the open Workbooks.

Comment: Try this link.http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/see-if-an-excel-workbook-is-open.html